# collect a string value from a function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

Hi i have a function where i am going to collect firstname lastname and phonenumber from a list of book

```
- (void)getnames
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

if (addressBook != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Succesful.");

    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];



        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

        NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        NSLog(@"FirstNAme::::: LastNAME::::::EMail:::  %@ %@",firstName,lastName);
        }
```

so from above function i get so many firstname and last name list when i check in the **NSLog**. so what is my requirement is how do i display all firstname and lastname in **DisplayNames** function  below in the form of array or list.so can anyone please tel me the code.how do i collect all the firstname and lastname from the above function.

```
-(void)Displaynames
{
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 options:

first, and easiest:

```
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSMutableArray *namelist = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];


NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
[namelist addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@ %@",firstName, lastName]];

[self Displaynames:namelist];
}
```

and at displaynames:

```
-(void)displaynames:(NSMutableArray*)names{
 for(NSString* name in names){
 NSLog(@"%@",name);
}
}
```

the disadvantage is that you can't use the first / lastname seperated. If you need this, take this code:

```
NSUInteger i = 0;
NSMutableArray *namelist = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];


NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
NSMutableArray *name = [NSMutableArray array];
[name addObject:firstName];
[name addObject:lastName];
[namelist addObject:name];

[self Displaynames:namelist];
}
```

and Displaynames:

```
-(void)displaynames:(NSMutableArray*)names{
 for(NSMutableArray* name in names){
 NSLog(@"%@ %@",[name objectAtIndex:0],[name objectAtIndex:1]);
}
}
```

This code is written right here in my browser, so it's untried.

Comment: y do i get this error    no visible interface for NSarray declares the selector addobject

Comment: [namelist addObject:name];

Comment: and namelist and name are created with `[NSMutableArray array];` ?

Comment: sorry namelist was NSArray i converted into NSMutablearry but when i run i am getting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType objectAtIndex:]:

Comment: and the code? ;) And which type do you added the array? I'd say you try to read a different type from the array than you've stored in.

Answer (score 0):

In getNames method.. you have an array of contacts.. through which you are iterating and printing logs.. why don't you change return type of getNames method to NSArray and use the same in Displaynames?

Answer (score 0):

Have a custom class as "User", declare attributtes such as firstName,lastName, etc in it. So in your getnames method make object of the custom "User" class and assign the corresponding properties, and finally assign the "User" object to a global mutable array. Use that array and iterate it to get all the details of user in your -(void)displayNames method. Simple.

P.S. Use proper naming conventions for method declaration.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

> -(NSArray *)getnames {
>       ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
>
> if (addressBook != nil) {
>       NSLog(@"Succesful.");
>
> ```
> NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
>
> NSUInteger i = 0;
> for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
> {
>     ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
>
>
>
>     NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
>
>     NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
>
>     NSLog(@"FirstNAme::::: LastNAME::::::EMail:::  %@ %@",firstName,lastName);
> }   return allContacts; }
> ```

In this way you have all firstName and lastName in your array and you can use this array in your

> Displaynames()

PS: declare allContacts in .h file

Cheers!